# Como popular um select

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Eu gostaria de saber como popular um `select` html com `jquery`, pois eu preciso puxar do banco de dados, porém, meu arquivo é .html e eu estou trabalhando com rotas então tem as views que são os arquivos .html e as rotas.

Aqui é o é View

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                <div class="search-products">
                  <h1 class="title-products">Escolha sua Peça:</h1>
                    <select name="desmarca" id="desmarca" class="input-text" required="required">
                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Marca</option>
                        {loop="$marca"}
                        <option value="{$value}">{$value.desmarca}</option>
                        {/loop}
                    </select>

                <button class="buscar-produtos" type="submit">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Aqui é a classe PHP

```html
<?php 

namespace Hcode\Model;

use \Hcode\DB\Sql;
use \Hcode\Model;
use \Hcode\Mailer;


class Marcas extends Model {

 public static function listAll()
 {

  $sql = new Sql();

  return $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_marcas ORDER BY desmarca");

 }

 public static function checkList($list)
 {

  foreach ($list as &$row) {
   
   $m = new Marcas();
   $m->setData($row);
   $m = $m->getValues();

  }

  return $list;

 }
 public function save()
 {
  $sql = new Sql();

  $results = $sql->select("CALL sp_marcas_save(:idmarca, :desmarca)", array(
   ":idmarca"=>$this->getidmarca(),
   ":desmarca"=>$this->getdesmarca()
  ));

  $this->setData($results[0]);


 }
 public function get($idmarcas)
 {

  $sql = new Sql();

  $results = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_marcas WHERE idmarca = :idmarca", [
   ':idmarca'=>$idmarca
  ]);

  $this->setData($results[0]);

 }


 
}

 ?>
```

E aqui é a rota

```html
$app->get('/products', function(){
 $page = new Page();
    
    $marca = Marcas::listAll();

  $page->setTpl("products", [
      'marcas'=>Marcas::checklist($marca)
      ]);
  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Deni.

Tenta isso no arquivo html:

```html
<select name="desmarca" id="desmarca" class="input-text" required="required">
     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Marca</option>
     {loop="$marca"}
          <option value="{$value.idmarca}">{$value.desmarca}</option>
     {/loop}
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, eu já consegui, agora estou com outro problema kkk vou editar meu post e se puder me ajudar agradeço